# No MethodError when trying get active record id

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

In model:

```
  def self.get_by_slug(slug)
    self.where("slug = ?", slug)
  end
```

In controller:

```
  #route: match '/category/:slug', :to => 'category#index', :as => "category_jobs"
  @category = Category.get_by_slug(params[:slug])
  @jobs = Job.where("category_id = ? AND expires_at > ?", @category.id, DateTime.now)
           .paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page =>    Jobeet::Application::MAX_JOBS_ON_CATEGORY_PAGE)
           .order("expires_at desc")
```

When I trying get category.id in controller I am getting error:

> undefined method `id' for #

Could somebody give me any advice?

Comment: Is "get_by_slug" even syntactically correct? Is that your exact code?

Comment: you are trying to get the id of a collection, so you need to get the first one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you expect a single record you should do:

```
@category = Category.get_by_slug(params[:slug]).first
```

because `.where(something)` doesn't return a single record.